# How to send 1000+ items List from one Activity to other in Android Java?

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, android-intent

I want to send a list of 1000+ items from one activity to another.
In other Activity there is a view pager and a imageview to show image. But if a list item is greater than  500 or near about 900, the app will crash, I think the list is not completely send and null pointer exception occure.

Comment: I'm sending a custom array list that contain data about wallpaper names, urls and details

Comment: *How* are you sending it currently? Also if you could [edit] your question to include the stack trace that would be helpful.

Comment: adapterWallpaper.setOnItemClickListener((v, obj, position) -> {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityWallpaperDetail.class);
                intent.putExtra(Constant.POSITION, position);
                intent.putExtra(Constant.ARRAY_LIST, (Serializable) items);intent.putExtra(Constant.EXTRA_OBJC, obj);
                startActivity(intent);
                showInterstitialAdNetwork();

        });

Comment: this Array list has 1000+ items, and when we pass 900 item click it show error

Answer (score 0):

You can't/shouldn't send large amounts of data from one `Activity` to another. There are better solutions:

1. Store data in your `Activity` and use `Fragment`s, which can access the data in the `Activity` directly
2. Store a reference to the data in a `public static` variable which can be accessed from any class at any time.
3. Store the data in a file or an sqlite database, where it can be read/written by any `Activity`

Answer (score -1):

I think send 1000+ list items to among activities is not a good practice, hence your app is crashed when you do this.

Better you can try different approach, perhaps Firebase Realtime Database can provide solution you need.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database

Comment: That's a crazy solution to a simple problem. Definitely wouldn't recommend this at all.